# Why doesn't Gaussian wavepacket broadening in position mean there will be a shortening in momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality

Many sources that say in free broadening of a Gaussian wavepacket, the momentum uncertainty (I think defined in terms of the range of 'significant' momentum amplitudes) is time invariant even as the Gaussian wavepackets broadens in position.

I'm trying to reconcile how this is consistent with the uncertainty principle.

My idea is that the uncertainty principle only loosely forces the 'bulk area' of the momentum distribution to have a spread that is inversely proportional to the 'bulk area' of the position distriubtion, but in special cases like this maybe the 'bulk area' is rearranged in such a way that the amplitudes of the momenta inside the original 'significant amplitude region' gets much larger, but not much wider?

Any thoughts?

Extras:

The reason I had this thinking about 'bulk areas' was because I was wondering how exactly the fourier transform of the position wavefunction (i.e. giving wavefunction in momentum space) is changed after this wavepacket broadening. Obviously its standard deviation hasn't changed, but I would expect there to be some difference since I though the FT doesn't lose any information from its input and its input has definitely changed. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to get back to this 'broadened' position wavefunction from the momentum wavefunction using an inverse FT.

Comment: Why do you believe uncertainty is a conserved quantity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> the momentum uncertainty (I think defined in terms of the range of 'significant' momentum amplitudes)

I'm not sure what you mean by this "range of significant momentum amplitudes". Uncertainty has an exact definition in QM. If you have a state vector $|\psi\rangle$ then the average of some observable $A$ is $\langle A\rangle=\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$, and the uncertainty is just the square root of the variance:

$$(\Delta A)^2=\left\langle \left(A-\langle A\rangle\right)^2\right\rangle$$

> My idea is that the uncertainty principle only loosely forces the 'bulk area' of the momentum distribution to have a spread that is inversely proportional to the 'bulk area' of the position distriubtion, but in special cases like this maybe the 'bulk area' is rearranged in such a way that the amplitudes of the momenta inside the original 'significant amplitude region' gets much larger, but not much wider?

Here too, I'm not sure how useful this "bulk area" idea is. You can directly calculate how the uncertainties of position and momentum evolve over time for the free Gaussian wave packet evolving according to the Schrodinger equation. Then you can show that the position uncertainty increases while the momentum uncertainty remains constant.

As pointed out in other answers, this doesn't violate the uncertainty principle. A violation would consist of *decreasing* uncertainties such that $\Delta x\Delta p\geq\hbar/2\pi$ is no longer valid.

To add some intuition here, the free particle Hamiltonian has no position dependence. Therefore, the propagator commutes with the momentum operator, and so any expectation values, variances, etc. for momentum measurements must be time independent.

> The reason I had this thinking about 'bulk areas' was because I was wondering how exactly the fourier transform of the position wavefunction (i.e. giving wavefunction in momentum space) is changed after this wavepacket broadening. Obviously its standard deviation hasn't changed, but I would expect there to be some difference since I though the FT doesn't lose any information from its input and its input has definitely changed. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to get back to this 'broadened' position wavefunction from the momentum wavefunction using an inverse FT.

We need to be careful here in distinguishing the wave functions (in terms of position or momentum) to the probability distributions, which involves the squares of the wave functions. Indeed, the wave functions are related by Fourier Transforms, but the probability amplitudes are not.

Assuming an initial wave packet of the form $\Psi(x,0)=Ae^{-ax^2}$ one can determine $\Psi(x,t)$ and $\Phi(p,t)$ for the free particle. I will not go through derivations, but this should be covered in various QM texts, or online. For reference here I was using Griffith's QM book section 2.4 and problem 2.22. Below are the real and imaginary parts of both $\Psi(x,t)$ and $\Phi(p,t)$ evolving over time (I have set all constants to $1$, so the actual numbers are not important):

[image]

[image]

We can see that both $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ are changing, and at each time they are related through a Fourier Transform. However, this idea does not carry over into $|\Psi|^2$ and $|\Phi|^2$; they are not related via direct Fourier transform:

[image]

[image]

Since the probabilities determine the statistics, we can see that the uncertainty doesn't change for momentum, but it gets larger for position. The uncertainty principle is still followed.

Comment: Ah okay I thought it could be something like this. So am I correct in saying the Uncerainty Principle does not mean that the uncertainties of x and p are inversely proportional, but their bounds? It's just confusing since some sources online make it seem like an increase in uncertainty of one must definitely cause a decrease in uncertainty of the other, but I guess this isn't the case then?

Comment: And I guess will the 'bulk area' idea, I was wondering how exactly the fourier transform of the position wavefunction (i.e. giving wavefunction in momentum space) is changed after this wavepacket broadening. Obviously its standard deviation hasn't changed, but I would expect there to be some difference since I though the FT doesn't lose any information from its input and its input has definitely changed. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to get back to this 'broadened' position wavefunction from the momentum wavefunction using an inverse FT.

Comment: @AlexGower $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ do not have to be inversely proportional. The only time you would know anything for sure (before just actually doing the calculations) is if you knew $\Delta x\Delta p=\hbar/2\pi$ and then you made a new state with a smaller $\Delta x$ or smaller $\Delta p$. Then you would know that the other value *had* to increase. But even then, it wouldn't have to necessarily be an inversely proportional increase. As for the Fourier Transform stuff, I will edit my answer accordingly when I have time.

Comment: @AlexGower I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, but there is a little mistake. You say that '$\Phi$ narrows', but I don't think it does. While it does get higher and higher frequency (because $\Psi$ gains support in larger positions), it is still always contained in the enveloppe $\sqrt{|\Phi|^2}$, which, as you noted, does not change.

Comment: @Andrea Yes, that is a good and correct point to make. Maybe it would be better to say the central peak narrows?

Comment: What would the significance be of just the central peak narrowing?

Comment: Would it not just be fine to say that the momentum wavefunction doesn't have any narrowing of uncertainty/peaks? The fact that it changes at all is reassuring to me as it means it is losing no information from the position wavefunction. From what I've read on the other answers, wouldn't it just be fine if its uncertainty didn't decrease at all, its shape just changed within the same envelope. (I'm talking about the momentum wavefunction here not the probability distribution)

Comment: @AlexGower Just so that we are on the same page here, wave functions don't have uncertainty. The momentum uncertainty (I term I really do not like) refers to the standard deviation of momentum measurements if you prepared multiple "copies" of the state and then performed momentum measurements on all of them. As for what you are saying, I am not sure what you are getting at. Yes, the momentum wave function is changing in that manner and the uncertainty isn't changing, but I've already shown that.

Comment: Hi, sorry I think we are on the same page, but I was just asking about why you were considering putting  'the central peak narrows' for the momentum wavefunction in your answer since (the way I'm reading it) that statement is sort of suggesting that there is some heuristic reduction in the wavefunction uncertainty, when we're both agreeing now that there need not be and there isnt. Why not just leave the answer as 'yes the momentum wavefunction CHANGES as it must since its a FT, but neither the momentum wavefunction nor the momentum probability distribution has any uncertainty changes'

Comment: @AlexGower The wave function and the probability distribution don't have uncertainties. It's the measurements themselves. I agree with the rest though.

Comment: Yeah sorry I shouldnt have used the word uncertainty, just more a general 'spread' word if you agree

Answer (score 10):

The uncertainty principle is simply $$\Delta X\Delta P\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$$ or $$\Delta P\geq\frac{\hbar}{2\Delta X}$$
If you increase $\Delta X$, the bound on $\Delta P$ is strictly lowered, not raised. Thus, $\Delta P$ staying constant as $\Delta X$ increases is a perfectly viable situation according to the uncertainty principle.

Comment: Ah okay I thought it could be something like this. So am I correct in saying the Uncerainty Principle does not mean that the uncertainties of x and p are inversely proportional, but their bounds? It's just confusing since some sources online make it seem like an increase in uncertainty of one must definitely cause a decrease in uncertainty of the other, but I guess this isn't the case then?

Comment: @Alex Gower The two are not inversely proportional; rather, the uncertainty principle just says that their products are greater than $\hbar/2$. This means that I could increase both of them arbitrarily, and since the product is still greater than $\hbar/2$, the uncertainty principle, at the least, allows it.

Comment: Thanks. Now my only final query is what happens to the fourier transform of the position wavefunction (giving the position wavefunction)

Comment: @Alex Gower This was covered in the now accepted answer; if you'd like me to show you how to derive exactly what happens, I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll just say a word on Fourier transforms, which might help clear up your intuition:

**Fourier transforms are complex.**

This means, for example, when transforming from position space to momentum space, there is a *phase* associated with each momentum value, in addition to amplitude.

If the momentum phase is uniform, this means the position spread is “transform limited”, i.e. minimum according to uncertainty principle. If, on the other hand, the momentum phase is non-uniform, then the position is [“chirped”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp) or worse. Then the position will be further spread out *for the same momentum amplitude spectrum*.

Edit to directly answer the question:

“Why doesn’t Gaussian waveform broadening in position mean there will be a shortening in momentum?”

Because the broadening in position can, in certain circumstances, be represented by a change only in the *phases* of the momentum spectrum (like a chirped wave, for example). Then the *amplitudes* of the momentum spectrum would remain the same.

Comment: This is interesting, are you suggesting something about how 'momentum uncertainty' in the FT Uncertainty principle is related to its spread in phases too?

Comment: @AlexGower yeah, it’s all just different ways to think about the same thing. The way you’ll get something other than the minimum $\Delta X \Delta P$ product is if the phases of one ($X$ or $P$) are non-uniform so that the other is not transform limited. I’d recommend playing around with Fourier transforms of various waves in mathematical software just to get a feel for it.

Comment: Just to double check, when you say in your original answer 'minimum according to the uncertainty principle', you don't mean satisfying the $\Delta x \Delta p = \hbar /2$ equality, you just mean 'a reduced uncertainty in x than if the momentum phase was non-uniform too' right?

Comment: And secondly to double check, you're not suggesting that momentum wavefunctions with non-unform phases are any 'less spread' or 'less uncertain' than ones with uniform phases i.e. you're not trying to suggest that in the Gaussian wavepacket example, the momentum wavefunction does get less uncertain due to having less unfirom phases, you're just saying that in fourier transforms it can be quite common for the envelope of one variable (e.g. position) to broaden while the envelope for the other (e.g. momentum) doesn't but it just has less uniform phases, right?